# Why does Chromium take up so much space when built from source?

Tags: chromium, build

When I build the Chromium browser from source, the size of the final "out" folder is about 60-62 **gigabytes**. Yet when I download and install either Chromium or Chrome using a binary file (which extracts all the necessary files for the browser to work), it is barely 250 or so megabytes big.
Why is there this huge difference?

I would really like to use Chromium that I build from source myself, but if it really will take that much space permanently, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try using the [strip](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strip.html) command on each executable file to remove symbols.  Review your build configuration.

Comment: I remember when browsers fit on a floppy.  62 gigabytes is a lot of floppies.